# Kendo Gantt for JQuery - Display Date/Time While Dragging Task

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, gantt-chart, kendo-gantt

I am developing a web application in Angular and it includes a Kendo for JQuery Gantt Chart. When a Task is dragged left and right I want to display the Start time to make it easier to leave the Task at the correct time. The tooltip seems to only appear when the mouse hovers over a static Task, as soon as the Task is dragged the tootip disappears providing no visual indication of the Start while being dragged.

Interestingly, there is good tooltip feedback if a Task is resized, but nothing if the Task is moved.

I can see there is a `move` event which I could hook into but I'm not sure how I could display the Task's changing Start property as the Task is moved.

Any suggestions very welcome.